# Need help with ANOVA partial proof

Tags: statistics

I'm taking an advanced statistics course right now and I'm having some difficulties grabbing the concept of ANOVA.

For a one-way ANOVA, we know that `SST = SSTr + SSE`. Proving that equation, at one point we encounter this equation: [Equation link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT7xu.png)

And that particular equation is supposed to be equal to `0` for the proof. I don't understand why it is equal to zero. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_i \sum_j (X_{ij}-\bar{X}_{i\cdot})(\bar{X}_{i\cdot}-\bar{X}_{\cdot \cdot})
&= \sum_i (\bar{X}_{i\cdot}-\bar{X}_{\cdot \cdot})
\underbrace{\sum_j (X_{ij}-\bar{X}_{i\cdot})}_{=0}
= 0.
\end{align}

To see why that term is zero for each $j$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n_i} (X_{ij}-\bar{X}_{i\cdot}) = \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n_i} X_{ij}\right) - n_i \bar{X}_{i\cdot}=0$$
by the definition of $\bar{X}_{i\cdot}$.